# IntelliJ keymap for remote desktop usage

Tags: intellij-idea, remote-desktop, keymapping

I notice that I cannot type Ctrl-Alt-B (Go To Implementation) in IntelliJ when I am using it via Remote Desktop. Is there a way that I can get keymap for IntelliJ that works through remote desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can be specific to your desktops and settings, there is no specific keymap for this environment as most keys will work fine.

The solution would be to use `Settings` | `Keymap` and change the shortcut for the **Go To Implementation** action to the one that works.